# Manage KVM VMs with Python like VBoxmanagement

Tags: python, kvm, libvirt

I have a VM which run under [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine), and I want to manage them with Python to do some functions like

1. Send a file to the guest VM
2. Execute a process or program in the guest VM
3. Dump a memory file used by the guest VM

How do I do that?

P.S.: I tried [Libvirt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libvirt), but I can't find functions to do the above ...

Comment: i asked libvirt guys in irc channel and they said it is not implemented yet

Comment: for dumping memroy file we can use win32dd or qemu pmemsave